# Rails Check If Record Is First

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, methods

I am iterating through a list of records. I need to check that if a record is first do XYZ and if not do ABC.  Unfortunately I cant do this:

```
user = User.first
```

or

```
user = User.find(:id)
user.first?
```

**Solution posted below**

Comment: Why cant you call Model.first?

Comment: i am first iterating through a list.  cant call it like this: user = User.first user.first

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: No question. More of an answer because i couldn't find this myself. Is this okay to do here or is there a designated area?

Comment: @Fdwillis I think if you found something worth sharing, you can do it in two steps. First post the problem as a question and secondly post the solution as an answer to it.

Comment: @usmanali okay, thanks

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Make method to grab next and previous records

```
def next 
  [Model].where("id > ?", id).first
end

def prev
  [Model].where("id < ?", id).last
end
```

### 2. Make method to check if record is first

```
def first?(record)
  [Model].first == record
end
```

### 3. check if record is first

```
records.each do |record|
  if record.first?(record)
    record.update_attributes(attr: record.attr + record.attr)
  else
    prev_rec = [Model].find(record.id).prev
    record.update_attributes(attr: prev_rec.attr + record.attr )
  end
end
```

4. returns `true` or `false`

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One improvement i would make sure that [Model].first is persistent so that it doesn't make a call to the database each time the loop is run.